# MySQL Fulltext won't find rows

Tags: php, mysql, search, full-text-search, match

I've got a car searching website and when I set up the search system it failed to give any dynamic searching. For instance, it's got 500 cars on their and ~5 are 'Toyota Ist'.

So when I search 'Ist' I get no results. (See query)

```
SELECT *,MATCH(aTitle, aDescribe, aCarModel, aCarWheels, aCarStereo, aCarIntTrim, aCarTrans, aCarDrive, aCarFuel, aCarPlate, aCarColour) AGAINST('toyota ist' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score FROM at_auction WHERE status = '1' AND aCarYear >= 1992 AND aCarYear <= 2012 AND startBid >= 0 AND startBid <= 20000 AND MATCH(aTitle, aDescribe, aCarModel, aCarWheels, aCarStereo, aCarIntTrim, aCarTrans, aCarDrive, aCarFuel, aCarPlate, aCarColour) AGAINST('toyota ist' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND closeTime >= '201201060842' ORDER BY opt_feature DESC, score DESC, score DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

But if I search 'Toyota Ist', i'll get a whole lot of Toyota Results. And the Ist car isn't neccessarily high in the list.

So the problem underlying is how do I set it up so that if someone searches just one word, say the cars model, it'll return the row... and how it can return the row if they search with multiple words like 'toyota camry', although that actually seems to work.

The MATCH fields are all FULLTEXT and aCarModel etc store the cars model and they're usually just one word like 'Ist' or 'Camry'.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If over 50% of the cars are "Toyota", then "Toyota" will be ignored in the search.  Also, the FULLTEXT doesn't index words under 4 letters.

50% limit and other tuning bits about FULLTEXT
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html

Minimum word length
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len